# Using TipKit in iOS16 and iOS17 codebase

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tipkit

I'm trying to utilize Apple's new `TipKit` where I still support iOS16. Is there a way to initialize the Tip without making the entire struct as `@available(iOS 17, *)`.  Example being

```swift
struct MainHomeEntryView: View {
   var myTip = MyTip()
      ....
}
```

error: `'SubmitTip' is only available in iOS 17 or newer`

Comment: I would create 2 structs View/ViewModifier that reuse everything else, TipKit is a little to specific for a bunch of/else

Comment: Thanks, if I'm following what you're suggesting  two `MainHomeEntryView` for the respective OS?

Comment: Yes, that would allow you to place the tips on specific reusable components. A ViewModifier would be more general.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem and came up with this small helper:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import TipKit


/// Small helper protocol for a tip that is available below iOS 17
/// so that we can pass tips around and have members storing tips,
/// as stored properties can't be marked with `@available`.
@available(iOS, obsoleted: 17, message: "Can be removed once we only support iOS 17+")
public protocol TipShim {

    @available(iOS 17, *)
    var tip: AnyTip { get }

}

@available(iOS 17, *)
public extension Tip where Self: TipShim {

    var tip: AnyTip { AnyTip(self) }

}


public extension View {

    /// Helper for making the `popupTip` modifier available for iOS <17.
    @available(iOS, obsoleted: 17, message: "Can be removed once we only support iOS 17+")
    @ViewBuilder func popupTipShim(_ tipShim: TipShim?, arrowEdge: Edge = .top) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 17, *), let tip = tipShim?.tip {
            self.popoverTip(tip, arrowEdge: arrowEdge)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }

}
```

With it, you only need a minimal amount of `if #available` checks. You only have to let your tip conform to `TipShim`:

```swift
struct MyTip: Tip, TipShim {
    // no additional implementation required, 
    // as this was done in the extension above
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```swift
struct MainHomeEntryView: View {
    var myTip: TipShim?
   
    init() {
        if #available(iOS 17, *) {
            self.myTip = MyTip()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        MyView()
            .popupTipShim(self.myTip)
    }
   
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is MyTip and MyView in your scenario? If you can give example

Comment: @SaadUllah This was taken from the OP's code. `MyTip` is an actual TipKit `Tip` and `MyView` is some SwiftUI `View`.

Comment: This will give an error in self.myTip = MyTip() as MyTip does not correspond to (any TipShim)?

Comment: @Joris Uh, I totally forget to mention that you need to add the conformance. I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Indeed, that's what I did in my code, but it's a good idea to complete the answer :) Thanks for the solution btw, works fine.